# Determining when the gradient of a function is parallel to a vector.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $G(x,y,z) = \left( \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} - R \right)^{2} + z^{2}$. If my calculations are correct, then $$\nabla{G} = \left(x \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right), y \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right), 2z \right)$$

How do I determine for what values $(x,y,z)$ is $\nabla{G}$ is parallel to $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: In general, two vectors are parallel if one is a (non-zero) scalar multiple of the other (each one will be so, you choose one arbitrarily). Alternatively, their vector product (or cross product) is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The vectors parallel to $(0,1,0)$ are
$$(0,\hbox{anything},0)\ .$$
So you need to solve
$$x \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right)=0\ ,\quad 2z=0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

This is just a minor change of David's solution.

The vectors parallel to $(0,1,0)$ are
$$(0,\text{anything} \not=0,0)\ .$$
So you need to solve
$$x \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right)=0\ ,y \left(2 - \frac{2R}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \right)\not=0\,\quad 2z=0\ .$$

Which is equivalent to :

$$x =0\ ,y \not=0\ ,2 \not = \frac{2R}{\sqrt{y^{2}}},z=0\ .$$